# Hassidim and white shirt

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

I always wonder what kind of white shirt the hassidim were wearing. They look different. I know you have to button these shirt from the left but the collar looks very different. Do you know what kind of shirt they were ? Maybe a brand or something ?

Here is an example: http://stefpix.com/slideshowpro_galleries/20090526satmars-marriott/album1/images/satmar_hasid_marriott090526_30.jpg

I know my question seems odd but I have heard that there is actually a reason why these men are wearing different shirts. I heard that the side of the buttons had something to do with chessed, apparently, the left side is connected to chesed.

Comment: Hey @maaaan, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Usually, it's the opposite: Chesed is connected with the right side and gevurah with the left. Also, what do you mean by "button these shirts from the left?" You mean that the buttons are on the left side (from the wearers perspective)?

Comment: Assuming that the answer is yes, the reason is so that the right side of the garment should be buttoned *over* the left, thereby putting chesed on top of gevurah.

Comment: I understand that different groups of Hassidim have the buttons on different sides. I think Satmar has the buttons on the left and Bobov has them on the right (or is it the opposite?)

Comment: @maaaan - I fidn the pic interesting, overall, and it's not b/c of the shirts. The expressions on the faces and, in particular, the hat on the middle front person seems off balance. Any idea what event or where this pic was taken? I like collecting certain pics of Hassidim

Comment: the left side is associated with strictness and the right side associated with kindness. Having the right side cover over the left is the idea that kindness should temper strictness.

Answer (score 12):

Hassidim generally wear three types of shirts:

1. A regular white dress shirt.[image: Regular]
2. As above, but with reversed buttoning, i.e. right-over-left. Pocket remains on left side of the chest. Basically identical to women's dress shirts, save for the bust shape.[image: Chassidic]
3. A "rebbishe" shirt with three or four differences from the above: 1. The sleeves have no cuff, but instead widen until about twice normal size at the wrist, where it has a simple stitch like at the bottom of the shirt. 2. The buttonable opening ends on the belly, where the button and hole parts are sown together in an upside down ​triangle (▽). 3. There are no pockets on the chest. 4. (Optional) The shirt may be very long, almost to the knees.[image: Rebbish]

Each type is available from several different brands, with negligible variations. All have standard point collars. Many hassidim will close the topmost button, even as they are not wearing a tie, thereby looking similar to a clerical collar.* This might be why you think the collar is non-standard.

As [HodofHod correctly stated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41244/hassidim-and-white-shirt#comment109966_41244), The right-over-left buttoning is to put [*chesed* over *gevurah*](http://www.aish.com/sp/k/Kabbala_12_Chesed_and_Gevurah_The_Two_Sided_Approach.html).

Source: Personal experience. (I wear number 3, including 3.4.)

---

<sup>* Therefore, some hassidim specifically leave the topmost button open – to avoid looking like a Christian cleric.</sup>

Comment: I dont know how to thank you for this wonderful answer. This is exactly what I was looking for ! What is the brand of the rebbishe shirt ? Where do you find these ? Is it the type of shirts the Satmar and others very haredi groups wear ?

Comment: (This really could be a separate, but related, question.) In USA and Canada, the most common brand rebbishe shirt is "Orient Super". They can be bought in Jewish dry goods stores in proximity to any significant hassidic population. While rebbishe shirts are mainly worn by family members of hassidic grand rabbis, the more extreme hassidim do so too. However, Satmar noticeably lacks a dress code. Most Satmar men wear regular or type 1 shirts.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I would really like to see what it looks like. Unfortunately there is no "hassidic shop" where I live (Paris). Do you have a picture maybe?

Comment: I'll try to take a picture of mine.

Comment: I hope you did not forget

Comment: @maaaan No, I'm just busy.

Comment: @maaaan There you go.

Comment: I have seen very religious lithuanians jews with that kind of shirt too. Is it the same as the Rebbische shirt ?

Comment: @maaaan I have been asking around, but have not gotten an answer yet. How would you "see" lithuanians with "that kind" (which kind?)? It isn't very noticeable when wearing a jacket on top (something a "very religious" person probably will do in public).

Comment: the shirt really seems to be the same but you're right, it's hard to notice with the jacket on top. The kind I am talking about is the rebbische kind. For example, I asked another question about the clothes of NK and the shirt seems to be rebbische.

Comment: @NBZ any idea why the sleeves on 3 are sort of short, coming down to just above the wrist?  It's something I've noticed on certain styles of bekishe too...

Comment: @yoel They are not very short, but the trunk is very long, so the sleeves appear short. However, yes, they are a little shorter, but as they end very wide, the bottom part hangs out to a normal length. If the whole sleeve had had normal length, the loose bottom edge would interfere with the hand.

Comment: @NBZ maybe I just have long arms...

Comment: Where can I get the regular white shirt with right over left buttons? The store I was ordering from stopped carrying shirts

Comment: @Dude Where are you located?

Comment: @Adám north eastern State in the US. No stores where I live carry this. Looking for one that will ship to me

Comment: @Dude I used to buy [here](http://elite-f-f-family-shop.edan.io/). Give them a call and ask if they can ship to Philadelphia.